# Could the heat from Venus be used to build a colony?

Tags: planets

I was thinking about using heat from Venus to build a colony there. So basically a machine capable of handling the heat in the first place absorbs the heat and converts it into electricity and stores as battery power so it could survive on Venus. This is because the amount of energy coming from the sun is mostly limited due to the thick atmosphere and clouds.

Would this be plausible or not? What is the reality check on this?

Comment: You can extract energy if there's a thermal gradient, is there something cold that can be used as a heatsink for this purpose?

Comment: Use the internal cold of the machine and then the heat would get converted to electricity so it would keep the inside of the machine cold so there is still a thermal gradient.

Comment: And what would stop the machine from getting hot with heat energy pouring into it (nothing is 100% efficient)?

Comment: Well, the heat will get converted to electricity, and also it could still be 99.9999999% efficient, and also while the heat gets in it gets converted to electricity.

Comment: The amount of electricity this machine is generating would be limited by the "amount of cold" that existed inside the machine. Every watt of electricity generated would require more than a watt of heat to seep into the machine.

Comment: It could still be pretty efficient so for every 1.00000000001 watts of heat, one watt is created. This means a reasonable amount of heat would still be created before this gradient becomes unusable.

Comment: Maybe you could do something geothermal, since Venus is the most volcano-covered planet in the solar system (I don't know the hard science well enough). This would be taking advantage of the core of venus being even hotter than the really hot atmosphere. Some scientists think the inside may be cooler - I don't know. I don't know if you could use some sort of balloon system to raise and lower your machine to the cooler upper atmosphere to allow it to cool off, then lower it back down (Venus has a thick atmosphere, though). I think there would be easier ways to generate power.

Comment: This is a good place to start researching this stuff https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terraforming_of_Venus

Comment: I have bad news for you: geothermal power plants aren't exactly known for being efficient, and I doubt your super reactor could get an efficiency much higher than 80%, even at theoretical levels (unless you add in a decent amount of handwavium, but then I don't see why worrying about whether or not it's possible to make it in the first place).

Comment: [Efficiency of such engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_engine#Efficiency) cannot exceed a specific theoretical maximum and there is no practical way you could reach your 99.99999999%.  It does not matter what you make the machine of or what form of power generation you use - this is limited by the laws of thermodynamics.  I would estimate the best efficiency possible at 60% for a colony on Venus.

Comment: It only says that 100% thermodynamic is impossible because there is still energy loss or gain but it could be possible right that 99% is fine right.

Comment: Suggest a bit of reading about thermodynamics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot_cycle  You can't extract energy from simple heat, no matter what temperature it's at.  You need a temperature DIFFERENCE.  That's why fossil fuel & nuclear power plants either have cooling towers, or are located by large bodies of water.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Physics aside**

You cannot turn heat into energy. I will try and give a more complete answer than the comments.

Pick up a rock. That rock is hundreds of miles from the centre of the Earth, towards which gravity is pulling it. That is a huge amount of gravitational potential energy. Why don't I just "build a machine" to turn all that energy into electricity? Well, in order to do that the rock would have to end up at the centre of the Earth, but there are already other rocks down there. So first I would have to dig them out of the way - but getting them out would cost as much energy as I stand to gain from dropping in my replacement rock.

Same thing with heat. You get energy by dropping heat into cold stuff (or by pouring coldness into hot stuff). The important thing is a slope.

**Your real question**

Fortunately Venus provides many heat gradients (slopes) you could exploit.

First there is Outer space, which is really cold (less than -270 Celsius). All you need is a clear line of sight to the darkness between the stars and you can release heat off into the darkness in the form of radiation (light). It might be very counter-intuitive, but the only way of using the heat all around you to create power is by having some cold, and the best way of making some cold is to radiate some heat away into space. This can already be used on Earth for cooling and refrigeration (https://spectrum.ieee.org/energywise/green-tech/solar/efficient-airconditioning-by-beaming-heat-into-space).

This approach would require you to be fairly high up in the air, floating above Venus's dense atmosphere that would block out your view of space if you were under it.

An alternative is to exploit the day/night cycle. It will get cooler at night, and that difference (day temperature vs. night temperature) can be turned into power with a little work (get some stuff cold at night then use it as your cold end at night). The big downside here is that Venus has really long days/nights. It should also be pointed out this only helps as much as the difference between the day and night temperatures, the fact that Venus itself is hot the whole time is useless to you (unlike above, where the fact that Venus is hot and space is cold would do some good work for you).

Comment: Could you use the Bosch reaction to extract some heat until the temperature falls below this limit? It is when Carbon Dioxide and hydrogen react to form carbon and water. It turns out that carbon has more energy than hydrogen. So we could take out some heat from Venus until the temperature drops for the reaction to happen. The reaction needs temperatures on the lower end from somewhere around 400-500 degrees Celcius on the lower end and 700 degrees on the higher end. Venus has around 400 degrees or slightly hotter temperatures for this sort of reaction.

Comment: I am afraid I don't know anything about the Bosch reaction, but what I said about exploiting heat gradients and the limits they impose applied to all possible machines/mechanisms you could think of to extract energy from heat (that obey known physics). But if you can extract energy from chemicals on Venus that is another matter and the restrictions I raised don't apply.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, with the clouds as heat sink

You can extract energy from the heat of the planet, but as many have pointed out, you need a heat sink. Assuming the machine works entirely on (and above) the surface, the best heat sink from the surface are the sulfuric clouds above. The surface has an average of 462°C, while the lower end of the sulfuric clouds is at 110°C. [atmospheric temperature given altitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Venus), [altitude of sulfuric clouds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfuric_acid#Venus)

### Some info on radiation

Radiative heat transfer is the same used by a [thermographic camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermographic_camera) to show the temperature of an object.

To radiate the energy it's possible to use a surface with the flat part toward the clouds above. What would happen is that said surface would radiate energy to any object in line of sight, and receive energy back from them. The energy flow depends on many factors like the inclination of the objects and their material, but to simplify the energy that you can emit is proportional to the fourth power of the temperature in kelvin, which means that if you increase +19% your temperature in °K, you double the energy that leaves you. The energy that arrives toward you depends on their temperature, so pointing your surface toward the clouds works better then keeping it vertically (you don't receive the one from the ground).

### Produced energy density with no CO2

Your heat sink must be colder then the surface, but the actual temperature would depend on the type of cycle used to extract energy from the heat, and the type of fluid used for it. [using those as rough reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_engine#Endo-reversible_heat-engines), if we assume the sink to be at 300°C (160°C below the heat source), its temperature in kelvin would be 573°K, and using the [Stefan–Boltzmann law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law) you'd have an outflow of 6.1 KW/m², while clouds would be at 383°K with a radiation of 1.2KW/m² (assuming they are a black body). This means that the resulting heat that it can dissipate is 4.9 KW/m². If the heat engine has an efficiency of 30%, then 70% of the inflow of energy needs to be dissipated to the sky. This means the maximum inflow from the surface is 7.0 KW/m², and the produced electricity is 2.1KW/m².

Using the [USA average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_electricity_consumption) of 1.377 KW per person, to power a little village of a thousand people you'll need 655 m² plus the space for actual heat engine. This without considering any additional energy needed to survive on Venus. As an indication your average nuclear reactor produces [881MW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_power_by_country) of electricity, which would require 419,523 m² (42 hectares) of radiating panels.

### Considering the CO2

CO2 is transparent to visible light, as its absorption is in the infrared, at wavelengths around [2, 2.7, 4.3 and 15 μm](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6174548/), [a graph here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905061051/http://www.globalwarmingart.com/wiki/File:Atmospheric_Transmission_png). At those wavelengths the CO2 will absorb the radiation to heat up, and emit radiation due to its temperature. A similar heat that comes from the air happens earth, as can be seen at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/153839/what-is-the-temperature-of-the-clear-night-sky-from-the-surface-of-earth this question (the sky from the surface on earth is not 2°K, but -30°C/-6°C).

The problem is that below the clouds, there is a sea of mostly CO2 at high density, kilometers thick, and at a temperature higher then the radiator. This means that most of the energy that reaches the radiator comes from the CO2 and not from the clouds above, which means that the type of surface considered above (black body radiators) would just heat up instead of cooling. I mean, if it wasn't like this, then the surface of the planet would be cooler then what it is.

This can be fixed in as similar way of the one used for the [daylight radiative coolers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiative_cooling#Architecture). The basic idea is to use a surface that reflects the wavelengths from which the CO2 emits, while emitting from all the other wavelengths. This would allow it to dissipate heat toward the clouds, without receiving the heat from the air in between. The energy produced per square meter would be even lower, though.